# Can't get past the login page with wget

Tags: linux, firefox, wget

I know that there are many similar questions, but they are very dated, and I have already tried pretty much everything and it still didn't work.
I'm currently trying to download a whole website using wget, but I can't get past the login page. Here is the list of things I've tried to do:

- Specify user and password as arguments. `wget --user="user" --password="password" $url`
- Load the session cookies exported from firefox in netscape format. `wget --load-cookies cookies.txt $url`
- Turn off robot exclusion, this was necessary, but not suffcient to scrape the site. `wget -e robots=off $url`

At the end this was my command `wget --mirror --user=$user --password=$password -e robots=off --page-requisites --convert-link --no-clobber --no-parent --load-cookies cookies.txt $url`

After all of this I still can't get past the login page. Is there anything else that I can do? Should I try using a different tool? Or maybe this site is too secure against tools like wget?

Comment: `--user` and `--password` together sets FTP/HTTP protocol authentication (using request headers) which is highly unlikely to be used with form based authentication.  Not knowing exactly how the site authenticates, there is really no way to answer your question as is.  If the site sets cookies after authentication you could try something like what is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6924582/how-to-call-a-form-based-authentication-from-curl-or-wget (not sure if there is a FF equivalent though)